# Best Practice to set a variable value(Hard Code) in Entity Class in java

Tags: java, class, entity

i am trying to set a string value(for variable env) as follows for all the objects:-

```
public class example{
private String env;
public String getEnv() {
        return env;
    }
public void setEnv(String env) {
        this.env = "IN";
    }
}
```

is it the right way to Hard code the variable value or any better way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need a setter when the variable is set to hard coded value? Set the variable when you are declaring it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Create a constants file which contains all the Strings necessary. Make
>   the String public static and final. Then use it in your code

```
Example: this.env =  ConstantsFile.IN; 

// tomorrow you can change its value to 
"pinnnn" only in the Constants file and not worry 
about changing every other filed that uses "IN" (now "pinnnn" :) ).
```

> This keeps your code clean and reduces dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is always going to have the same value, declaring it as final is the best practice.

`private final String env = "IN";`

If the variable is not dependent on objects, declare it as static as well

`private final String env = "IN";`

Answer (score 0):

Don't hard coded, just keep the method taking any value, the specify the value you want out side the method.

```
public void setEnv(String env) {
    this.env = env;
}
```

Then:

```
String currValue = "IN";
obj.setEnv(currValue);
```

But if you don't want to change the value, then don't create a setter method at all.

```
private final String env = "IN";
```

and then just read the value.

```
public String getEnv() {
   return env;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it directly in the attribute definition:

```
public class Example{
    private String env = "IN";
    public String getEnv() {
        return env;
    } 

    public void setEnv(String env) {
        this.env = env;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not start class names with small letters, because it's against convention.

You can just set the value in constructor, like that:

```
public class Example {
    private final String env = "IN";
    public String getEnv() {
        return env;
    }
}
```

Have in mind that this way you will not be able to change this value anymore. For that you would need to define a proper setter:

```
public void setEnv(final String env) {
    this.env = env;
}
```

and remove the "final" of field "env".