# Is it appropriate for a subclass to restrict it's parents member variables?

Tags: java

Is this an appropriate design? Is there an alternative?

```
package com.company.core;
public Foo{
    private String appName;

    public void setAppName(String appName){
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    public String getAppName(){
        return appName;
    }
}

package com.company.application;
public Bar extends Foo{
    private String appName = "MyFirstApp";
}
```

In my application Foo is an entity class for a table set up by our DBA. They are expecting a free-form field to identify the application storing information in that table. So we have a generic class that accepts a string.

Now in our application, we want to use that class, however the application name will always be the same and we want to enforce this. It's simple enough to hide the superclass's variable like this, but what do we do about the public getters and setters? Is there a better way to restrict the value of a field?

Comment: Note that `private String appName = "MyFirstApp";` is not setting the value of the parent class field. Use the `super` setter to do that.

Comment: That was intentional. I was trying to get the variable to not be modified by the parent class's setter. But that idea was proving problematic. Validating the input of the setter as user3360944 suggested was too obvious of a solution and I over-looked it. :)

Comment: Do you need the setter? Could the Foo class access it's appName String with the final modifier (so it's a constant)? This was discussed [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658131/best-practice-to-set-a-variable-valuehard-code-in-entity-class-in-java) on S.O. also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is appropriate and reasonable to restrict the values of an attribute in a subclass.  In fact you can (and should) override the setter to thrown an IllegalArgumentException if the value attempted is not your specific value. No need to worry about the getter.